# Aparent XML anomaly on its data structure

Tags: c#, xml

I found an XML situation that I cannot understand. A device is sending me an XML structure that contains something like this:

```
<element>
    2
    <subelement>1</subelement>
</element>
```

This XML is valid, as checked on several online validators. However, it does not make sense to me. I am not sure how could I map this to a strong-typed object in C# or how to interpret it.
I tried to find documentation on this or some other examples, but no luck.

Can anyone explain this? Provide maybe a link to some documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's certainly well-formed XML.

An element that has both child elements and text nodes among its children is referred to as "mixed content". Mixed content is usually used for document structures like this:

```
<p>This is <b>important</b></p>
```

but of course you can use it any way you like.

As to what it means, only the person who designed it can tell you that.

Representing mixed content in conventional programming languages is tricky, which is why there's a big advantage in using languages designed for processing XML, such as XSLT and XQuery. We can't really say how this particular instance should be represented without knowing the full range of structures that might possibly appear in the input. If the input is always a single number followed by a single element, then you will want a different representation from the case where it is any number of elements and any number of numbers, in any order.

Answer (score 1):

You can map this XML content to this class:

```
[XmlRoot("element")]
public class Element
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("subelement")]
    public string Subelement { get; set; }
}
```

`XmlTextAttribute` indicates that the member must be treated as XML text.

Answer (score 0):

As for the validity, I am not sure as I really think that looks invalid, as it defines two elements within block scope.

But for representing it in an object model, I would do something like this if I needed to work on it/parse it:

```
class Element {
    private int value;
    private Element[] subelement;
    //...


}
```